# How common is the word "hubris" in spoken language?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I wonder how common the word *hubris* is in spoken language. Does it sound hubristic to use it in an informal context?

In Italian we don't have such a word although in specific contexts one can use *hybris* as the ancient Greek term.

Comment: Certainly not as common as the characteristic.

Comment: It is fantastically popular in comedy circles.

Comment: It's highly uncommon in spoken language. So much so, that I have no idea how the word is pronounced; though I've read it many times.

Comment: Common enough that most people know what it means. I've used it in speech before. Not all the time of course, but when the shoe fits...

Comment: It doesn't sound *hubristic* but rather *pompous* or *recherche* or preening. Showing off without any point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> hubris

would stick out very uncomfortably in informal speech, and is pompous sounding even in academic writing. Even if a word is highly used, or rarely, it will still have other features like vulgarity/tabooness (like very common swear words), technical context (carburetor), or, as in this case, register (like perhaps or indeed). That is to say that frequency isn't the only thing that gives a word color or appropriateness.

As a style recommendation, I would not recommend using the word hubris around your football hooligan comrades, they might make you pay for the next round. And unless your tea party pals are discussing Greek tragedy, it make a monocle or two drop. But it's totally on for the crossword gang.

As to its frequency though in writing, here are the words of mostly equivalent frequency:

> impasse
>   imp
>   immerse
>   ilk
>   humerus
>   **hubris**
>   honeydew
>   homophobia
>   hindrance
>   hiker
>   highfalutin

These terms are all easily recognizable by adults. They are not rare, but they are also not everyday words (hiker seems out of place here, I'd expect that to be much more common). These words are more educated, like impasse, humerus, and hindrance.

For perspective with the corpus used, these are around the 20140 index of frequency, where the list starts:

- 1: you, I, the, to, a
- 1000: plenty, guilty, jerry, fired
- 10,000: unorthodox, trusty, trough, trolly
- 15,000: forger, fictitious, fizz, feasible
- 20,147: hubris, honeydew, homophobia, hindrance
- 30,000: dermis, dermatological, deregulation, deputation.

Those at the 30K mark are still very recognizable.

Note the Zipf pattern in action: the less frequent items will have less difference in frequency to the point that many will have the same number of occurrences and then by the extraction method I used, they are sorted alphabetically together.

This short list was created using word frequencies from https://www.researchgate.net/project/Word-prevalence-measures-for-62K-English-lemmas. The source doesn't have to be terribly accurate; a lot depends on the corpus but presumably with a large enough corpus a difference of one or two mentions may put you in a not too distant bin.

Comment: I guess I must be numbered among the "crossword gang" - I tackle the Guardian crozzie almost every day, and I get quite irritated if I can't finish it on my own. I commented elsewhere re finding hundreds of instances of ***hubris*** from site-specific searches of "lowbrow" newspapers such as *The Daily Mail* and *The Daily Mirror*, but...

Comment: ...a site-specific search of [theguardian.com](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB799GB799&ei=A8A8W8qWIqnmsAf3hbboDw&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftheguardian.com%2F+%22hubris%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftheguardian.com%2F+%22hubris%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...33217.39523.0.40333.2.2.0.0.0.0.110.211.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.tLLiTnpfs7g) claims ***over 12 thousand hits***. Many of them might indeed be from the crossword/word puzzle section, but that would still leave an awful lot that ain't!

Comment: @Mitch thank you for the answer! The problem with Italian natives is that a lot of words that in English sound pompous are frequently used in Italian and this can cause some monocle dropping

Comment: @Gitana As you well know, half of English is Latinisms and Hellenisms, but that tends well to the educated side. But the cognates in Italian won't have the same implications as to register, won't sound as highfalutin.

Comment: I use it unselfconciously, but only in reference to an action that did indeed result in one receiving their comeuppance. For unconsummated doom, I use *impudence*. But perhaps I'm also in the crossword gang.

Comment: @PhilSweet Is there any difference in the meaning of _hubris_ and _impudence_? _Impudent_ seems to imply a childish connotation that _hubristic_ doesn't have

Comment: That's a neat study, but the question asked about spoken (and informal spoken at that), and the study seems to be about written. The answer will differ hugely.

Comment: @smci Yes, of course there could be a big difference between spoken and written. It's easier to answer questions in a supportable manner on electronic text, not so easy to support reliably with spoken. I gave my assessment about spoken first, and then gave quantitative information about written.

Comment: @Gitana In my head, "impudence" is filed under "describes a thing that a person does" and "hubris" is filed under "desribes a affectation or element of a person's character"… but that's just context and mediocre memory. …

Comment: I would be grateful if anyone can find another wordlist with frequencies. The corpus for the given one seems to be idiosyncratic ('I' and 'you' are concerningly too common in this one).

Comment: @Mitch And what the hell is a _jerry_? A jerry can? The forename Jerry? The nickname for a German? I think its presence is an _unorthodox hindrance..._ ;-)

Comment: @NigelTouch I'm surprised nobody had already called me on that. I noticed it too and it seems very strange for it to be such high frequency. The samples of 4 are not terribly off as a whole but individually each word might be questioned. The word list is presumably from blind tokenization of a corpus, with no separation into different meanings/uses.

Answer (score 9):

As noted, its usage has been growing constantly in the English language:

According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hubris) the term hubris is:

> - ***Used Occasionally***.

[Hubris](https://www.wineverygame.com/words/hubris.html):

> - ***In modern usage, hubris refers to extreme arrogance that can often cause a person to look ridiculous***. It can be applied in situations of business, school, or any social interaction. People might act with hubris if they lead a meeting as though they are completely knowledgeable on information they've never learned. Similarly, a student who believes they are better than everyone else because of a superior test grade would have considerable hubris.
> - ***The contemporary use of hubris can be applied in any situation relating to overbearing pride. The use of hubris is meant to emphasize just how intense one's arrogance can be***. Hubris indicates supreme overconfidence, which in turn can lead to foolishness or even a downfall. An inflated ego is not built on a solid foundation of fact or knowledge; therefore, anyone with hubris tends to isolate or destroy their social standing or relationships. Hubris is never a good thing because it is excessive, damaging pride.

(wineverygame.com/words)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how common it is in spoken English, though.

Comment: @OliverMason - Please see Collins note

Comment: @user110518 'top 30000' isn't very informative given that most people's vocabularies have less than that.

Comment: @Mitch - I agree, but I think the informative part is where they say "used occasionally".

Comment: Just as a note the world average for anglophones _spoken_ vocabularies is 5000 words or less.

Comment: @user110518 'used occasionally' doesn't mean much unless you know what other words are also in that same group, and in the groups 'used often' and 'used rarely' for comparison.

Comment: @Mitch - used occasionally means that it is not common usage. I think that's a helpful indication. If you have a more helpful one please post an answer.

Answer (score 8):

On [wordcount](http://www.wordcount.org/main.php), *hubris* is ranked 39704 of 86800, and is ranked only two lower than *shipwrecked*.

On [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hubris&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chubris%3B%2Cc0), *hubris* does show a rising usage trend, with a dip in recent years.

I would say it's common enough that it would be useful to know what it means.

Comment: *hubristic*, the adjective, also shows a very similar trend.

Comment: Big chunk of rising usage is that "hubris" [is mentioned](http://wiki.c2.com/?LazinessImpatienceHubris) as part of **"virtues of a (great) programmer: Laziness, Impatience and Hubris"**. Note that the link above (wiki.c2.com) is the original first wiki, still around :-)

Answer (score 1):

These days it is very rare to hear the word *hubris* in spoken English, or even see it in modern writing. Normally these days we usually say *pride* or *arrogance* but *hubris* is occasionally used, specifically because it is something of an archaic term, when talking about people with an established record or reputation who it's felt should have known better.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hubris&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chubris%3B%2Cc0), the word ***hubris*** (first recorded use by OED, 1884) has been steadily gaining traction over the past century.  It may have come from ancient Greek, but it's actually a relatively *modern* usage, not "an archaic term".

Comment: Google n-grams are based on published books, rather than informal spoken language, so they are not really reliable evidence in this case.

Comment: @Oliver: The word didn't really *exist* in English before the OED's first cite (which refers to it as "Academic slang", while providing an "inline definition"), and the next cite isn't until 1923. My "evidence" for the ongoing / rising currency of the term in *spoken* English is based on a lifetime of using and hearing it - almost exclusively as an "academic" usage when I was a student half a decade ago, but it's well out there in more general use today. Definitely not "archaic", whether you believe that NGram supports my position or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard hubris used as a spoken word half a dozen times in 30+ years and always when someone is reading it from a text from the first half of last century.

Comment: @Ash: Well, as I said, back when I was an English Language / Literature undergraduate, I only ever came across it in academia. I would point out that a site-specific search on [The Daily Mail](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB799GB799&ei=-L88W56wPIuykwWnqajYAQ&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2F+%22hubris%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2F+%22hubris%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4429.8902.0.9698.11.11.0.0.0.0.119.1189.0j11.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.MbzNWnWK9Rs) ~(hardly an "academic" source!) finds 881 instances...

Comment: ...and if you think the Mail isn't "lowbrow" enough for my point, I see there are 258 hits for ***hubris*** in [The Daily Mirror](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fmirror.co.uk%2F+%22hubris%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB799GB799&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fmirror.co.uk%2F+%22hubris%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.16855j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I won't descend to the depths of ***The Sun***, but I've no doubt even they would be quite happy to use it today. It's no longer that rarefied.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes that's in England, and in writing where it is far more common than the spoken word. England is also far from being the only country the language is spoken, you do realise this yes?

Comment: @Ash: If you compare the AmE / BrE corpuses on my NGram link you'll see that the steady increase in traction (and *current* level of usage) are about equal for both. Apart from a slight uptick in BrE around the mid-60s, perhaps occasioned by the fact that C. S. Lewis used it in *Poems* (1964). Sure - it's probably outside the productive vocabulary of the *majority* of native Anglophones - but that's just because most people aren't very articulate, and don't know many different words *in total*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Again that's a comparison of _written_ language, this falls outside the parameters of this particular question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [the comparison with the original spelling](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hubris%2Chybris&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chubris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chybris%3B%2Cc0) is interesting too, especially the sudden decline after 1959

Comment: @Márton: Well, OP says that "original" spelling *(**hybris**)* can be used in Italian anyway. But you might be interested to note that the full OED first records that  version in *English* in 1920, some decades after ***hubris***. It never cauight on though.

Comment: Neither _pride_ nor _arrogance_ is a good substitute for _hubris_ though (says I, a non-native speaker, but I am unusually brave today).

Comment: FWIW, I would pronounce *hubris* as /hoo-briss/ or perhaps /hyu-briss/--but I don't think I've ever had occasion to pronounce it.  The related word *hybrid* is pronounced "high-bridd"; it is much more common than *hubris*.

Comment: @pipe By definition hubris is overbearing pride or arrogance so while neither has quite the vehemence of hubris than can be made to be substitutes.